# Is there any command to optimize all MySQL tables one by one automatically?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.1

I execute below command line statement to optimize a table:
`optimize table tablename;`

Is there any command or statement which can optimize all the tables one by one of the selected database?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I usually use **mysqlcheck** with --optimize and --databases combination. **mysqlcheck** is a command-line interface for administrators to check, optimize and repair tables.

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -p --optimize --databases myDatabase
```

Here is the MySQL doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlcheck.html

Max.

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14169/discussion-between-ursitesion-and-mfouilleul)**

Answer (score 7):

You can use information schema to generate the statements you need:

```
SELECT Concat('OPTIMIZE TABLE ',TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE table_schema='yourdb';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could script it and place all tables on a single line

## ALL TABLES IN THE CURRENT DATABASE

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
MYSQL_DATA=mydb
TBLLIST=""
COMMA=""
SQL="SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=DATABASE()"
for TBL in `mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -D${MYSQL_DATA} -ANe"${SQL}"`
do
    TBLLIST="${TBLLIST}${COMMA}${TBL}"
    COMMA=","
done
SQL="OPTIMIZE TABLE ${TBLLIST};"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -D${MYSQL_DATA} -ANe"${SQL}"
```

## ALL TABLES IN ALL USER DATABASES

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
TBLLIST=""
COMMA=""
SQL="SELECT CONCAT(table_schema,'.',table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE"
SQL="${SQL} table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
for DBTB in `mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"`
do
    TBLLIST="${TBLLIST}${COMMA}${DBTB}"
    COMMA=","
done
SQL="OPTIMIZE TABLE ${TBLLIST};"
set -x
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: This seems to take a long time on my server and I cannot see aprogress. can you add some output which table is optimized in the loop?

Comment: I adapted your script to optimize all databases so it is run one by one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33541722/1069083